# svn release tag from multiple trunk locations

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I hope this makes sense to everyone.  My group at work writes test scripts we use to test our hardware.  We store the scripts in SVN as follows:

```
/trunk/  
....../test1/  
............/test1_exes/  
............/test1.py  
....../test2/  
............/test2_exes/  
............/test2.py
```

When we release these scripts for use on the hardware the following directory structure is used:

```
\test1_exes\  
\test2_exes\  
test1.py  
test2.py
```

In other words the scripts and exe folders are all stored in a common folder not individually like they are stored in SVN.

We would like to tag all tests that belong to a specific release in the second folder structure.  That way we can perform a simple svn export and our test folder would be ready for execution.  So like this:

```
/tag/release1/  
............./test1_exes/  
............./test2_exes/  
............./test1.py  
............./test2.py
```

I had hoped I could do this by using TortoiseSVN and doing a select-all on the contents of a test folder and performing the tag.  Unfortunately the tag/branch option isn't available when doing it this way.  Only when selecting the parent test folder is the tag/branch option available.  This results in a release structure that matches the first directory example.

Does anyone know of a way to do what I need or will I be stuck making multiple svn calls to tag each child file/folder individually?

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tagging in SVN is just a cheap copy of existing structure, so what you are trying to achieve is not quite the way it SVN would do. **Tagging should not involve any changes**, as tag should point to single revision.

### The only "SVN proper" way I see is:

Create standard "Tag" on full folder structure, then check it out to local machine, and invoke script that will create the folder structure you need. Your deployment procedure should not be mixed with your repo strucuture - if one day you need to do deployment to multiple clients, requiring different folder structure for each, will you mess around with your repo tags structure every time?

### If you still want to do this:

In TorotiseSVN repository explorer, you can `right-drag` your folders to new folder (make sure you copy them, not move them). But you have to do this for each "test" folder separately, you can not "select-all" files from all "test" folders (at least I am not aware). But every single copy action will be new revision.

Other way would be to create shell script which would go foreach test folder in your repo and copy them to target folder. Again, every copy action would be new revision (although you can use [svnmucc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html) tool to make it single revision).

This approach has (at least) one downside: As comitting to Tag is not recomended, if a bug is found in your release, how do you fix it?

[Recommended](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html) way is:

> It may be that you need to make further changes to a release which you
>   have already tagged. The correct way to handle this is to create a new
>   branch from the tag first and commit the branch. Do your Changes on
>   this branch and then create a new tag from this new branch, e.g.
>   Version_1.0.1.

Now you should create "tag" branch that has structure completely different than "standard" branches. Sounds bad.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ivan.  I know my proposal isn't exactly a valid way to use SVN but it should be better than what we've been doing which is to simply export each test from SVN into a share drive.  Which means there is no way to track changes.  At least this method, along with your suggestions provides some level of control.